# Switching large batteries between 12 V and 48 V connections

Tags: batteries, dc, solar-energy, high-current, toggle-switch

I have four 200 Ah batteries that I am using to drive two separate really high current loads. The first load is 12 V at around 400 A and the second is 48 V at around 120 A.

I was wondering if I could use 12 V and 48 V winch motor solenoid contactors to switch the batteries between 48 V and 12 V when needed. Would this be safe to do or is there a different option to consider?

I also do have a 5 A battery balancer between the 48 V system, so it should never really be out of balance and the charge controller from the solar array detects between 12 V and 48 V automatically. Any advice on this subject would be appreciated.

[image: Hope this helps but this a drawing with two battery boxes separated by switches so it can switch between series and parallel]

Comment: Could you please draw some wiring diagram?

Comment: I think you could do it, but I would highly advise against doing it under load, because there could be a short time where the batteries are not balanced so in my opinion you need two sets of contactors, one that separates the batteries from the load and another that rearranges them.

your current wiring diagram does not show the whole story so I suggest yo upgrade to show all batteries and all connections

Comment: Also probably needs a lot of thought about safety so that your batteries don't explode if one relay gets stuck. Also the balancer should probably not be connected while the batteries are in parallel.